# Group information form database

Tags: ruby, grouping

I need help to group information from database table. My table (animals) looks like:

```
id   name   animal
1    john   dog
2    kate   cat
3    jack   mouse
4    jack   cat
5    john   cow
6    jack   elepahnt
```

and I want to group them by the name so that it looks like this:

```
john: dog, cow;
kate: cat;
jack: mouse, cat, elephant;
```

I tried functions `group`, `group_by`, but they didn't work. I can do it by making a function with `if`, and putting all necessary information in the arrays, but are there any built-in functions that can help me?

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet, please.

Comment: Is this an ActiveRecord question, a Sequel question, a MySQL question, a MSSQL question, a Ruby transformation of SQL data question...?

Answer (score 0):

A version using `Enumerable` methods. Expects records with methods `name` and `animal` (like `ActiveRecord`).

```
Table.all.group_by(&:name).inject({}) { |a, (k,v)| a[k] = v.map(&:animal) }
```